# Does Eclipse/Java run on WIndows 7 64 bits?

Tags: java, eclipse, 64-bit

I noticed a lot of problems when trying to run Eclipse and Java on 64 bits MS Windows. Is it supported? Is this something I shouldn't do or try to do?

I extracted Eclipse helios 64 bits zip, then I installed Java and I was able to run Eclipse for day or two.

Now I have been working hard for a few hours to reproduce a working Eclipse and I am arriving at the conclusion that probably it is not such a good idea. It is 64bits OS, 64 bits Helios, 64 bits Java. Could it possibly work?

Java runs on billions of device supposedly but I doubt if it will ever run 'again' on my laptop. If it does work I suppose it is just luck.

Comment: It works just fine, it's probably something else...

Comment: I have 64bits OS, 64 bits Helios, 64 bits Java , I don't find anything abnormal. You need provide detailed error or message

Comment: yes. everything works great with those config. if you don't post some error nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: is java path set correctly... ?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall everything and try downloading fresh again. I am using eclipse in my 64 bit windows machine for long time now and it works fine.

Try using versions which I am using currently. These work perfect for me - 
jdk1.7.0_21 and jre7 and eclipse version 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Now, I am using 64-bit Windown 7 with JDK 1.6.xxx. There is no any problem.

Make sure `JAVA_HOME` to do enviroment variable. Otherwise, you need to configure `vm` configuration in `eclipse.ini`.
You also note of that memory setting for eclipse. It is base on your physical memory.

eclipse.ini

```
.....
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```